# ElasticBeanstalk deployment logs out all Symfony users

Tags: symfony, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I’m using ElasticBeanstalk to deploy to a single VM on Amazon AWS. I use the normal Amazon Linux AMI (PHP 7.1) and write my app in Symfony (3.3) using FOSUserBundle.

Everything works well, but every time I deploy, all my users get logged out. Which is annoying, if I deploy 10 times a day and they might be in the middle of a long form. I suppose it is because each new deployment creates a whole new app at `/var/app/current` and so the Symfony app’s `var/cache` and `var/sessions` don’t exist.

Is there an elegant and ElasticBeanstalk-compatible way to keep the sessions even after deployment? I suppose a link (which is generated each deployment) showing to a centralized `var/` folder instead of a clean `/var` folder might help?

Would this be the right way to go about it even? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Not a solution, but a workaround with other benefits: use another way to save sessions. I'm using Redis and it gives some performance benefits too.

Comment: Thanks, was stuck in »file« mode, but I suppose using Redis (or something like Memcached?) might do the trick. Thanks!